# "Invalid cursor state" error when reading from database

Tags: java, ms-access, selenium, jdbc, webdriver

I am trying to fetch the details from Access Database and use those values in my selenium script, but somehow i am unable to do so.. Although i was able to successfully connect to the database and print the values in the console. I am unable to use the same values in the script. This is the code that i was using. Kindly let me know were am i going wrong.

```
package AccessDB;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class Sample_Access_DB_Test {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String dbLocation;
    public static Connection con;
    public static Statement smt;
    public static ResultSet rs;
  @Test
  public void f() throws Exception {
      //Database Location
      dbLocation = "D:\\AccessDB's\\Userinfor1.accdb";

      //Connecting to the Database
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ADB");
      System.out.println("Connection Establised Successfully");

      //Creating DB statement
      smt = con.createStatement();
      System.out.println("Statement Successfully Created");

      //Executing Created Statement
      rs = smt.executeQuery("Select * from Userinfor1");
      System.out.println("Query Executed");

      while(rs.next()){
         System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
         //System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
         //System.out.println(rs.getString(4));
        }
      driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys(rs.getString(2));
      /*
      driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("gopi_krishna28");
      driver.findElement(By.id("login-passwd")).sendKeys("gopikrishna28");
      driver.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();*/
  }
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://www.yahoomail.com/");
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
  }

}
```

and this is the error that is thrown

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state

Answer (score 1):

After you execute the SELECT query your `while(rs.next()){` loop iterates through the rows in the ResultSet and dumps values to the console. After that loop exits the current position of the ResultSet is not pointing to a valid row; it is positioned *after* the last row.

So, on the very next line

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys(rs.getString(2));
```

when you try to use `rs.getString(2)` you get an error because the ResultSet is not positioned at a valid row.

You'll either need to:

1. get rid of the `while(rs.next()){` loop and perhaps just do a single `rs.next()` to position the ResultSet at the first row (assuming that one exists) and then carry on from there, or
2. if your SELECT query returns multiple rows and you want to do some processing for each row then keep the `while(rs.next()){` loop but move your Selenium code *inside* the loop where calls like `rs.getString(2)` will be able to return values for the current row of the ResultSet.

Comment: hmm okey... i tried another way... well it sort of worked but not totally. i replace the while statement  with if statement                                                       if(rs.next()){    driver.findElement(By.id(rs.getString(2))).sendKeys(rs.getString(3));    driver.findElement(By.id(rs.getString(4))).sendKeys(rs.getString(5));    
}                       but the thing here is its only accessing the columns and not rows.. how do i get it to access rows? any idea on this?